# Magento 2.3.4: Elasticsearch 7 is not working

Tags: magento2

**I have installed an elastic search in my local server successfully. I am not able to reindex the catalog search indexer. Please check the attached screenshots.**
[image]

Elastic Search Version Is : 7.6.0

Magento Setting :

[image]

Comment: whats is your elk version and magento settings

Comment: Did you find any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Magento as far as I know doesn't support Elasticsearch 7. [Check here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26220)

I think you need to setup correct Elasticsearch Version. Check the screenshots below.

> Elasticsearch Version 6.8

[image: Elasticsearch localhost:9200]

> Successfully connected

[image]

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
```

**Output** : Catalog Search index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:44

Answer (score 0):

You have installed Elastic Search Version 7.6.0 but in the configuration you have used search engine as Elastic Search 6.

Check if you have Elastic Search 7 available in your configuration As of Adobe Commerce ver. 2.4.4 I could see the below configurations

[image]

So either you have the  update your configuration to use the correct ES instance or downgrade your ES instance.

Now coming back to the error,

In older versions of Elasticsearch, every index could have multiple types per index, which led to ambiguity when the same name appeared in different mapping types that are backed by the same Lucene field internally. This is not supported in the latest es versions.

However as already suggested in the error message, set the include_type_name parameter to True should solve this issue.

We can see this setting is set in "Elasticsearch7" module
\Magento\Elasticsearch7\Model\Client\Elasticsearch::addFieldsMapping

[image]

Hope this helps.