# Magento2: After Installing Elastic search and Configuration product page not working

Tags: magento2, php, elasticsearch

I have installed elastic search 7.8 and configured it with Magento 2.3.4 but when I open the product page, it's not working, and also when I search any product it shows me an error.

```
> Type Error occurred when creating object:
> Magento\Framework\Search\Response\QueryResponse, Argument 3 passed to
> Magento\Framework\Search\Response\QueryResponse::__construct() must be
> of the type integer, array given, called in
> /home/ubuntu/environment/the-new-craftsmen/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php
> on line 121
```

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22773

Comment: Please check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/307156/magento-2-3-4-elasticsearch-7-is-not-working

Comment: did you update your server configuration also did you change the config in the admin to match the correct version. finally did you reindex and recache the website?

Answer (score 1):

I got temporary solution for this.

Go to `vendor/magento/framework/Search/Response/QueryResponse.php`

replace line 43 with following

```
public function __construct(array $documents, AggregationInterface $aggregations, /*int*/ $total = 0)
```

Line no 89 replace with following

```
public function getTotal()
    {
        return $this->total;
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That is because Magento 2.3.4 doesn't support ElasticSearch 7.

Support has been [introduced](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/elasticsearch/es-overview.html#es-spt-versions) with Magento 2.3.5 and Magento 2.4.

Even if you get rid of that error, there might be others to follow.

Upgrade to Magento 2.3.5 or Magento 2.4 and it should work perfectly.